# Type erasing `AsyncMapSequence<AsyncThrowingStream<Element, Error>, Element>`

Tags: swift, swift-concurrency

I'd like to type erase `AsyncMapSequence<AsyncThrowingStream<Element, Error>, Element>`. My consumer doesn't care whether the sequence has been transformed, or how it has been transformed.

Ideally this could be type erased to the original stream type (`AsyncThrowingStream<Element, Error>`). Is that possible?

This is my attempt:

```
extension AsyncMapSequence {
    func eraseToAsyncThrowingStream() -> AsyncThrowingStream<Element, Error> {
        AsyncThrowingStream { continuation in
            Task.detached {
                do {
                    var iterator = self.makeAsyncIterator()
                    while let element = try await iterator.next() {
                        continuation.yield(element)
                    }
                    continuation.finish()
                } catch {
                    continuation.finish(throwing: error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but that yields this error...

```
Fatal error: attempt to await next() on more than one task
```

I'm also not super sure why transforming a stream becomes a sequence

Comment: Think my error might have been related to another issue (consuming the same stream in more than one task). Without that I think this code does in fact work. :)

Comment: You probably want to look at AsyncChannel for this kind of problem: https://github.com/apple/swift-async-algorithms/blob/main/Sources/AsyncAlgorithms/AsyncAlgorithms.docc/Guides/Channel.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this can be done more simply and generally with `init(unfolding:)` (I haven't done much testing on this, but I don't see any reason it shouldn't work):

```
extension AsyncSequence {
    func eraseToAsyncThrowingStream() -> AsyncThrowingStream<Element, Error> {
        var iterator = self.makeAsyncIterator()
        return AsyncThrowingStream(unfolding: { try await iterator.next() })
    }
}
```

I recommend reading over the [AnyAsyncSequence thread](https://forums.swift.org/t/anyasyncsequence/50828/1) in the Swift forums for some further (and future) thoughts on the underlying question.

Comment: Works great, thank you! Some great extra reading there. Will add this to the long list of things to try and understand completely!

Comment: Would the new `AsyncThrowingStream` get cancelled when the underlying `AsyncSequence` is completes?

Comment: No, it would just complete as when `.next()` returns nil. (Completion is not the same thing as cancellation).